# Appcode breakpoint by hit count (pass count)

Tags: appcode

Is there a way to enter a pass count to a breakpoint the way it is possible in IntelliJ or Xcode? E.g. the breakpoint is ignored 9 times when running through a loop, but the tenth times it stops the debugger.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such an option yet, we'll add it in the next version: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-5458